# Concatenating videos with ffmpeg produces silent video when the first video has no audio track

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 3 mp4 files:

- 1.mp4 - Has video, no audio
- 2.mp4 - Has video and audio
- 3.mp4 - Has video and audio

I have created a clips file (clips.txt) for concatenation:

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
file '3.mp4'
```

I run the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i "clips.txt" -c:a aac -b:a 160k -y "out.mp4"
```

The file that is produced has video but no audio, presumably because 1.mp4 has no audio track.

If I rearrange clips.txt so 1.mp4 is not first, out.mp4 has an audio track.

Is there a way of forcing ffmpeg to use audio? I guess it would have to produce a silent audio track for any silent videos.

Thanks!

Comment: or add a silent track first to the one without any audio, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/how-to-add-a-new-audio-not-mixing-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg for some ideas.

Comment: That was what I was thinking I'd need to do. I was hoping for a cleaner solution, but I decided I'd just stick to that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles onto this and wants to achieve the same thing as I do, I solved it as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i "1.mp4" -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -shortest -y "new_1.mp4"
```

What this says is:

- Take 1.mp4 (which is the video clip without audio) (-i "1.mp4")
- Generate the minimum silence required (-f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -shortest)
- Output the result (-y "new_1.mp4")

From here I concatenate as I did before, but replacing "1.mp4" in clips.txt with "new_1.mp4"

Comment: For the silent audio make sure to match the channel layout and sample rate of the other inputs. For example, 44.1kHz stereo audio: `-i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100` (these are the default settings for the [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc)).

Comment: Oh. I didn't know to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, consider adding `-c:v copy` to just re-mux the video instead of also re-encoding it.